# Chaining ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#select returns additional records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having a strange situation where just calling something like `article.comments` doesn't bring up all the records it should, but if I add `select, everything comes up. I'm seeing things like this:

```
article.comments               #=> []
article.comments.select(:id)   #=> [#<Comment:0x12341234 id: 1>]
```

Took a look at the SQL and there's basically no difference, it's selecting `comments.*` vs `comments.id`. What could be responsible for this?

Comment: could you show me your Article class?

Comment: class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :comments
   end

   class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :article
   end

Comment: never mind -- solved it

Comment: ok. if you don't mind, please post your solution as answer here to help others facing same problem